# Background does not follow border radius

Tags: html, css

I have the following code implemented on a website to blur the objects behind the box it spans:

```
<style>
            
                html, body {
                border-radius: 15px;
                background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
                margin:   0;
                padding:  0;
                width:    auto;
                height:   auto;

              -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(.5em);
              backdrop-filter:blur(.7em)
          }
```

Works fine so far, except that the background color does not follow the border-radius, resulting in this:

border_radius:
[image: border_radius]

I've tried to hide overflow, setting a solid border and adding a -webkit-border-radius, but that hasn't worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. CSS without its corresponding HTML Markup is useless in most cases to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `border-radius` on `html` because it is a part of browser view:

```css
html, body {
                border-radius: 15px;
                background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
                margin:   0;
                padding:  0;
                width:    50px;
                height:   50px;

              -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(.5em);
              backdrop-filter:blur(.7em)
          }
```

It is not like regular html tags:

```html
<div id="test" style="
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    margin:   0;
    padding:  0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(.5em);
    backdrop-filter:
    blur(.7em);
"></div>
```

Comment: I have applied a border radius on html successfully. What system are you using? I’m on Safari IOS at the moment.

Comment: Have you ran the above code? Mine: Chrome + Windows.

Comment: Yes it’s OK in terms of having a border radius.

Comment: Just checked; not working on my phone; Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

In a case where the background does not follow border-radius, I think this is because the background differs from the actual tag itself, since it is "a portion of the HTML" that the current tag sits on. While the border represents the extreme line around the tag as seen in the "box-model".

For more info on CSS Box-Model see:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp